# Does ReportExecutionService.Render Method run in the background?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

If I process a report using the ReportViewer and the report takes 5 minutes to process, I'm staring at a spinning green circle for 5 minutes, unable to do anything else.

Ideally, I'd like to give control of the application back to the user to do other things while the report is processing, so I'd like to use the ReportExecutionService.Render Method, but I want to be sure that I don't have to wait for the report to finish processing to get control of th app back.  (I know that I'll have to create another screen where they can select the completed report to view.)

**Can someone please confirm that the ReportExecutionService.Render Method is a background process, and control returns to the user immediately.**

[The perfect solution would be to use a Report Subscription but I'm having trouble with that.  That will be my next post if the above approach doesn't pan out.]

Comment: What kind of app are you talking about? ASP? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: updated tags to include ASP